# Making a template that requires a template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make a templated class that only works on other templated classes.

My attempt looks like:

```
template<typename T<K,V>, size_t COUNT>
class DoubleTemplate { ..... };
```

But this give a compiler error where I try to specify `T<K,V>`.

Is there a good way to require that the typename can only be a template on two params?

Comment: what are you trying to make with that? T is a good type. You can use typenames as T::K or T::V if there are such type definitions in T...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

```
 template <template<typename, typename> class T, size_t count> 
 class DoubleTemplate { ... };
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename K, typename V>
class Foo {};

class Bar {};

template <template<typename, typename> class T, std::size_t COUNT>
class DoubleTemplate {}; // you need class T, not typename T, to be corrected in C++17

int main()
{
    DoubleTemplate<Foo, 10> dt;
    // DoubleTemplate<Bar, 20> dt2; //oops, Bar is not a 2-param template class
}
```